Control location of tooltip produced by tooltip-show
When I evaluate (tooltip-show "test"), it is my expectation that the tooltip will appear right next to the current location of point. However, the tooltip instead appears in a seemingly random location far from point.
Why is this happening? Is there a way to make it appear next to point?

Did you read the docstring of the function? Do C-h f tooltip-show  and note that it says "...Otherwise, the tooltip pops at offsets
specified by 'tooltip-x-offset' and 'tooltip-y-offset' from the
current mouse position" (emphasis added). That's because the function is not usually evaluated by hand - instead, it is called as a result of some mouse action, so it makes sens to keep the tool tip next to the mouse cursor.

that makes a lot of sense! In my mind I read "mouse" as "point" (as in, the location of point within the emacs buffer). So I guess something along the lines of my workaround is necessary if I want it positioned near "point", and not near the "mouse" position.

Here is a not great workaround:
(defun my:tooltip-by-point (msg)
   "requires fullscreen to position correctly"
   (interactive)
   (let ((left (car (window-absolute-pixel-position)))
         (top  (cdr (window-absolute-pixel-position))))
   (x-show-tip 
      msg
      (selected-frame)
      (append `((top  . ,(+ top  410))  ;; 410 found by trial and error
                (left . ,(- left 205)))
              tooltip-frame-parameters)
      tooltip-hide-delay
      nil nil))) ;; DX DY irrelevant due to PARMS containing `top` and `left`

It requires the "magic numbers" 410 and 205 to adjust for some sort of offset that is occurring. You may need to adjust these numbers.

(window-absolute-pixel-position) seems to be inconsistent across emacs sessions. maybe some other way of getting the position of point would be better

See Coordinates and Windows in the Emacs Lisp Ref manual.
